# Support of a codeword in a binary linear code proof

Tags: proof-techniques, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

Let $C$ be the binary linear code with the following generator matrix

$G= \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$

The *support of a codeword* is the set of coordinate positions in which the code word has nonzero entries. Let **$w$** $\in C$ be a code word of weight $4$. Show that there is no code word of weight $3$ in $C$ whose support is a subset of the support of **$w$**.

I think I have worked out that the codewords of weight $4$ in $C$ are: $\{(1001011),(0010111),(0111001),(0101110),(1100101),(1110010),(1011100)\}$ so does this mean that the support is $\{(1,4,6,7),(3,5,6,7),(2,3,4,7)$ and so on..$\}$?
Then the codewords of weight $3$ are $\{(1101000),(0110100),(0011010),(0001101),(1000110),(1010001),(010001)\}$ ? with support of  $\{(1,2,4),(2,3,5),(3,4,5)$ and so on..$\}$?

I'm not sure if this is right so far? But this is as far as I can get and do not know what to do next to show that there is no code word of weight $3$ in $C$ whose support is a subset of the support of **$w$**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a codeword of weight 3 existed whose support was a subset of a codeword of weight 4, then you must have a codeword of weight 1 (since the difference of codewords is also a code word).

A codeword of weight 1 has one 1 and the rest zeros. Now, can you show that these don't exist?

Comment: Can I say that a codeword of weight 1 doesn't exist because $C$ has a minimum distance of 3?

Comment: Also I can't quite get my head around _why_ if a codeword of weight 3 existed whose support was a subset of a codeword of weight 4, then you must have a codeword of weight 1 I know you say the difference of codewords is also a code word but I can't see the link between this and supports/subsets

Comment: Your code is a linear code (so sums/differences of codewords are also codewords). Take the difference of a codeword of weight 4 and the supposed codeword of weight 3. The codeword of weight 4 has ones in 4 positions, and the supposed codeword of weight 3 has ones in 3 of the 4 positions. So, when you do codeword of weight 4 - codeword of weight 3, you get a codeword which is 1 in the support of weight 4 codeword but not in support of weight 3 codeword and zero otherwise. so it has weight 1.

Comment: If you show that C has minimum distance 3, then you're done by combining it with what I've stated: adding/subtracting the supposed codeword of weight 3 with the codeword of weight 4 would give you a weight 1 codeword. The existence of this contradicts distance 3.

Comment: Sorry I'm still finding it quite hard to visualise. As an example when I do a weight 4 codeword - a weight 3 codeword, I get 1001011-1101000. Which gives 0100011, weight 3 not weight 1? Could you give an example so I can see how you get weight 1?

Comment: The key word is *subset*. So, for example, if 1001011 is the weight 4 codeword, the weight 3 codeword would be 1001010 or 1001001 or 1000011or 0001011(turn one of the 1's in the weight 4 codeword into a 0).